# 3rd Party UI components for .net Compact Framework?

Tags: .net, user-interface, compact-framework

I have a .Net compact framework application with a frankly unimpressive UI.

My win32 app uses Dev Express components and looks great, but I can't find anything similar for the compact framework.

Can anyone recommend components that will jazz up my UI?

Does such a thing exist, oram I going to have to owner draw my components or even worse use native code?

Answer (score 3):

A number of vendors provide controls for the Windows Mobile environment.

[Component One Mobile](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioMobile/)

[Pocket PC Controls](http://www.pocketpccontrols.com/)

[Resco Mobile Forms Toolkit](http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/overview.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[OpenNETCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/) is a large collection of classes, components and controls for the compact framework. I'm not sure that they have anything that'll jazz up your UI, but it'd be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

I really like Resco's mobile controls. They are solid and the support is good.

I purchased a few controls from Pocket PC Controls. They are not bad, but if you run into bugs its hit or miss if you hear back from the developer. Basically, it doesn't seem like the  components are constantly being updated.

Resco on the otherhand has frequent updates, new features and new components.

Comment: http://www.resco.net/developer/