# What are some good 3rd party controls for Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile

We're developing a windows mobile 6.1 application and would like to make the user interface look better than the standard battleship grey.  Has anyone had any experience with 3rd party controls that can make a windows mobile app look like a WPF/Silverlight/Iphone - like interface?

Comment: possible duplicate of [3rd Party UI components for .net Compact Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907/3rd-party-ui-components-for-net-compact-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some useful-ish replies in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907/3rd-party-ui-components-for-net-compact-framework) question.

Answer (score 2):

Please check : http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/overview.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the linked answer also mentions Resco.