# Center align images in ListView (Compact Framework)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I am working on a mobile application where the main menu is created by a `ListView`. I have the following as my screen now:

[image: Current application screen]

I am trying to align the icons in a better way. What I need is to align the icons to the center (both horizontal and vertical)! I am looking for something like this:

[image: Required application screen]

I am not able to find any property or methods that can help me achieve this. Any idea how to do it on Compact framework? I am using CF 3.5 and C# to build the application.

Any idea or solution highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know that's not possible with the ListView.

The fastest way is probably to drop a bunch of PictureBoxes on your form, and implementing the Click-event. A more reusable way is to create a custom control and build your own version.

There is also the option of paying for a third party library of controls. If that's your preference then that question has been asked here before: [3rd Party UI components for .net Compact Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907/3rd-party-ui-components-for-net-compact-framework)

Comment: I am not looking at 3rd party library controls. But it feels strange to know that its not possible with the native controls..

Comment: The limitations of the CF can be frustrating in times. Users today are becoming expectant of very nicely looking UIs. The CF doesn't give much help for that and learning to create custom controls becomes helpfull very quickly. Even in our most simple applications we use at least our own ImageButton.

Comment: Great.. so I think I will have get by hands dirty trying to build it as custom control. Thanks for the info.