# How to add styling to a form using .net compact framework

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am developing an application for a MT2090 barcode scanner/mobile computer. This application is being developed using Visual Studio 2008 for smart device development. I am using .net compact framework V2.0.

is there a way to add a Style sheet to this to give the buttons a better appearance or add boarders around items? I am coding in vb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default styling theme support in Compact Framework.

You may code in html and CSS and host a webview to show the UI. Adding callbacks enable you react on button clicks etc.

But there are also [GUI toolkits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907/3rd-party-ui-components-for-net-compact-framework) like Resco MobileForms toolkit to have a different GUI.

Alternatively you may subclass buttons etc and make your own visual styles.